# Exporting union of interfaces as type throwing error

Tags: typescript

I am writing a react/redux based application using Typescript. I want to expert union of action interfaces so that I can use in the reducer as ActionType. But the compiler is throwing error that there is no such export found.

```
// Filename: store/app/app.actions
import {
  Language,
  LANGUAGE_SELECTED,
  User,
  USER_FOUND
} from './app.types';

interface UserFoundAction {
  type: typeof USER_FOUND;
  payload: User
}

interface LanguageSelectedAction {
  type: typeof LANGUAGE_SELECTED;
  payload: Language
}

export type AppActionTypes = UserFoundAction | LanguageSelectedAction;
```

I am inporting AppActionTypes in reducer like the following

```
import {AppActionTypes} from './app.actions';
```

And getting following error

Line 4:  AppActionTypes not found in 'store/app/app.actions'

Following links validate that what I am doing is correct

I am using Typescript version 3.5.3 and babel 7.4

[Typescript: Union Type as interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516451/typescript-union-type-as-interface)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

[How to type Redux actions and Redux reducers in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482241/how-to-type-redux-actions-and-redux-reducers-in-typescript)

Comment: Is your file `store/app/app.actions.ts`?

Comment: yes, this is the complete path of the file.

Comment: But with the extension `.ts`?

Comment: Yes with the extension ts.